# How to pass "this" with ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think I have done this before but I forgot how to do it. Here is what I want to accomplish:

In the html, I have this setup:

`<md-card ng-repeat="card in cards" data-link="{{card.link}}" ng-click="showCardDes(this)">`

In my Angular script, I set this up:

```
  $scope.showCardDes = function(e) {
    var tempUrl = $(e).attr('data-link');
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: tempUrl,
    });
  };
```

I also tried in html:

`<md-card ng-repeat="card in cards" ng-click="showCardDes({{card.link}})">`

and in my Angular script:

```
  $scope.showCardDes = function(url) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: url,
    });
  };
```

I remember when I did it before it involved something with setting up a ng-model, but I seriously cannot find the documentation either online or in my hard drive. `>.<`

I forgot to mention I also tried this:

`<md-card ng-repeat="card in cards" class="noselect hietim {{card.size}}" data-link="{{card.link}}" ng-click="showCardDes($event)" md-ink-ripple>`

And in my Angular Script I used:

```
  $scope.showCardDes = function(event) {
    var tempUrl = $(event.target).attr('data-link');
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: tempUrl,
    });
  };
```

This will return:

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as others said you can use $event for this but in your case it is not the angular way of doing it. You should pass your model as parameter and read its property;

```
<md-card ng-repeat="card in cards" ng-click="showCardDes(card)">
```

and in your controller;

```
$scope.showCardDes = function(card) {
  var tempUrl = card.link;
  $mdDialog.show({
    controller: DialogController,
    templateUrl: tempUrl,
  });
};
```

Comment: Wow this seems to be a more simple approach. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Using $event is perfectly acceptable with AngularJS, even if what you are clicking has an existing model.

Comment: as i said "in your case" and never said $event is not acceptable. But when it can be done the change with model manipulation it should be done that way. The other approach is more jQuery way of doing it.

Comment: I think your are both right, I would like to know how to use `$event` to get this done too. Too bad only one answer can be accepted.

Comment: Thanks.  I was making it too hard.  This is very easy.

Answer (score 9):

If you pass in `ng-click="showCardDes($event)"` you can access the element within the `$event` object.

So in your javascript it would look like this:

```js
 $scope.showCardDes = function($event) {
    var btn = $event.currentTarget;
    var tempUrl = $(btn).attr('data-link');
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: tempUrl,
    });
  };
```

Comment: I see, I might forget to use `currentTarget`, let me also give this a try.

Comment: This gives me a reference error `ReferenceError: $event is not defined`, I think the problem is at me, but I don't put my finger on it.

Comment: I see, you used `$event` in your angular script. And I used `event` this is why. Your method also worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `ngClick` directive [passes a named `$event` property](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L64) to your handler, which you can use to access "this" (aka the event target).

```
<md-card ng-click="showCardDes($event)" ...>
```

Then your controller may look like this:

```
$scope.showCardDes = function(event) {
  var tempUrl = $(event.target).attr('data-link');
  $mdDialog.show({
    controller: DialogController,
    templateUrl: tempUrl,
  });
};
```

Comment: Hey there, I actually had tried this approach too. I should mentioned it. In console log it tells me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

I would also like to mention that you can instantly pass the card, like this

```
(click)="someFunction({card})"
```

And if you desire the element itself, then you can add a #variableName, and pass that.
Here is a example of them both together.

```
<tr *ngFor="let card of cards" (click)="randomFunction({card}, cardRef)" #cardRef>
      <td><span class="ms-1">9 of Diamonds</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The question is about AngularJS, not Angular 2+